# how to update a label when user is typing into a textview?

Tags: swift

Hey I'm new to Swift and having some problems with my code.

Suppose I have two objects:

```
IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!
IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
```

So I want "label" to displays the current number of characters that is in the  textView.

But I'm not sure how to make the "label" update automatically whenever the text in the textView changes (when user types in/ deletes)?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just register an "observer" object with `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification)). In the callback of that observer object you change the labels text.

[This blog post](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swift-property-observers/) may interest you.

---

#### Edit

Reference for [NSTextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textDidChange:), which actually functions the same. Just use `textDidChange(_:)`.

Comment: Thanks. But can i use this func for Mac OS? thought UIxxx is for iOS?